# VBA Type Mismatch error with Join function

Tags: excel, vba, join

I'm running into a type mismatch error with the last line. Any ideas?

```
Dim language As String

Dim langOps(0 To 2) As String

If CheckBox10.Value = True Then
    langOps(0) = CheckBox10.Caption
End If

If CheckBox15.Value = True Then
    langOps(1) = CheckBox15.Caption
End If

If CheckBox29.Value = True Then
    langOps(2) = CheckBox29.Caption
End If

language = Join(langOps, [, ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`""` not `[]`

```
language = Join(langOps, ", ")
```

(`[]` is the evaluate shorthand syntax and `[,]` evaluates to an error which cannot be coerced to the string `join` wants hence the error)

Answer (score 1):

Fails because you use square brackets >>`[]`<< instead quotes `""`.

`language = Join(langOps, [, ])`  >>> Wrong

`language = Join(langOps, ", ")`  >>> Right